# Mongodb Aggregation How can i merge this subdocument of subdocument?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I'd like to combine these data, this two data has the same root _id, and video field has the same songs._id value. Finally, I want to merge this video datas that has same song._id to array of video under same songs data and same root i mean,

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e328f15b7e4937f52c67679"),
    "name": "HoYoung",
    "like": 0,
    "view": 0,
    "songs": {
      "_id": "32f3156c-ed37-40dc-af96-dcbf53a84a58",
      "name": "testName",
      "lyrics": "testLyrics",
      "like": 0,
      "video": {
        "_id": "1255c77b-f3f6-466a-bd1a-0124555e5592",
        "like": 0,
        "view": 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e328f15b7e4937f52c67679"),
    "name": "HoYoung",        
    "like": 0,
    "view": 0,        
    "songs": {
      "_id": "32f3156c-ed37-40dc-af96-dcbf53a84a58",
      "lyrics": "testLyrics",
      "like": 0,
      "name": "testName",
      "video": {
        "_id": "f08a433a-e120-459f-8bf1-1f55081dbf82",
        "like": 0,
        "view": 0
      }
    }
  }
]
```

to

```
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e328f15b7e4937f52c67679"),
        "name" : "HoYoung",
        "like" : 0
        "songs" : {
            "_id" : "32f3156c-ed37-40dc-af96-dcbf53a84a58",
            "name" : "testName",
            "lyrics" : "testLyrics",
            "like" : 0,
            "view" : 0,
            "video" : [{
                "_id" : "1255c77b-f3f6-466a-bd1a-0124555e5592",
                "like" : 0,
                "view" : 0
            },{
                "_id" : "f08a433a-e120-459f-8bf1-1f55081dbf82",
                "like" : 0,
                "view" : 0
            }]
        }
    }
```

How can i do this? group? problem is i cannot do grouping subdocument of subdocument

Answer (score 0):

You need to `$group` by `songs._id` (and root `_id` in your context) and accumulate `video` sub-document inside a temporal `video` array (we store inside `root` top level document to merge in the next stage).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$songs._id",
      root: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      },
      video: {
        $push: "$songs.video"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: "$root.name",
      like: "$root.like",
      songs: {
        _id: "$root.songs._id",
        name: "$root.songs.name",
        lyrics: "$root.songs.lyrics",
        like: "$root.songs.like",
        view: "$root.songs.view",
        video: "$video"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9zW-B3OovpK)

Comment: Oh Thank then, i success to merge video with same songs, then, how can i merge these two data with same root._id ?? i mean these query is merge these two video wtih same songs._id i mean.. group?? what i want to do is merging with same root._id not songs._id... thanks for your help

Comment: @조호영 Have you tried provided aggregation? Execute it first, it does exactly what you are expecting to do